# Laravel Mix infinite loop when using npm run watch [L5.6]

Tags: laravel

Here's my webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .combine(['public/js/app.js', 'node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js'], 'public/js/app.js');
```

I am launching js task, then combining all js files into a single one.

When i run `npm run dev` everything works as expected, but if i run `npm run watch` and then edit a file that being required in app.js (custom.js) this way:

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./custom.js');
```

Then save the changes, mix is compiling very long, after it finishes my changes not reflected. Am i doing something wrong there?

Comment: I totally hate laravel-mix i rather use webpack itself. Try to remove node_modules and package-lock.json and run npm install again. it might help.

Comment: didn't help, i've opened my app.js while `watch` were running, and noticed that contents of my app.js is flickering, when i stop `watch` it goes back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop issue was because i used the same name when combining js files - `app.js`.

Correct way is not using combine, i've included my owl carousel file in app.js:

```
require('owl.carousel');
```